# Matrix power of eigenvalue decomposition: why do we only need to apply the exponent to diagonal matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-decomposition

I have read the following definition:

> Diagonal matrices $\mathbf{D}$ can efficiently be raised to a power. Therefore, we can find a matrix power for a matrix $\mathbf{A} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ via the eigenvalue decomposition (if it exists) so that $\mathbf{A}^k = (\mathbf{P}\mathbf{D}\mathbf{P}^{−1})^k = \mathbf{P}\mathbf{D}^k\mathbf{P}^{−1}$.

Why do we only need to apply the $^k$ to $\mathbf{D}$? I know there is just some rule that I do not know but I could not figure it out.

Comment: Note that in order to apply this trick, you need to diagonalize matrix $A$, which does not work for all matrices. It notably works for all real symmetric matrices, and for all real matrices whose eigenvalues are all real and different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the $P$ terms cancel out. Take for example $k = 2$, and consider
$$A^2 = (PDP^{-1})^2 = P D P^{-1} P D P^{-1} = PD I DP^{-1} = PD^2 P^{-1}.$$
This pattern persists for $k > 2$.